# How to make PDF show filename instead of title using program?

Tags: python, pdf, pdfbox, pypdf, pdfminer

https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/default-to-show-file-name-vs-title-of-doc-when-converting-from-word-to-pdf/td-p/9673161

I'd like to show filename instead of title for a bunch of PDF files. I want to do this with a program or a command line. Is there a way to do so (python is preferred over other languages)? Thanks.

[image: Adobe Acrobat dialogbox]

Comment: Can you explain the contents of that link and how they relate to the rest of your post?

Comment: That is how to do it in acrobat. I want to do it with a program.

Comment: _That is how to do it in acrobat._ Do what? Links are fragile, please explain whatever needs explaining in your post itself.

Comment: I can see the link without problem. See the reply from the 3rd message.

Comment: "You can access document's initial view settings by opening pdf file in Acrobat > click File > Properties > Initial View > Window Options.

Show > file name/document title. (below is the screenshot):"

Comment: That still isn’t clear. _I’d like to show filename instead of title for a bunch of PDF files_ Show filename instead of title **where**? You’re omitting a bunch of context.

Comment: To answer your question, **yes, I’m sure this is feasible**. Case closed. Again, Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, it is not a substitute for guides, documentation, or tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

With PDFBox:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(...);
PDViewerPreferences vp = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getViewerPreferences();
if (vp == null)
{
    vp = new PDViewerPreferences(new COSDictionary());
}
vp.setDisplayDocTitle(false);
doc.getDocumentCatalog().setViewerPreferences(vp);
doc.save(...);
doc.close();
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not quite familiar with PDFBox. Would you please let me know the complete steps to make this work starting from installing PDFBox?  https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi

Comment: @user1424739 Stack Overflow is not meant to provide documentation, guides or tutorials.

Comment: You asked about PDFBox, so you got java code, not python code. IMHO it was a valid question but if you have never used java, then you'll have to learn how to use an IDE, a library (use the pdfbox-app download), build and run. I recommend Netbeans.